# Creating binary matrix from two data rows in R

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe, contingency

I have a big data frame with two variables, one of which are names and the other id numbers of persons related to that names, and I want to create a matrix where each name is an observation and each id a variable.

For example

```
names     ids
peter     23
peter     20
peter     25
john      25
john      22
mike      21
```

And I want to obtain a matrix where

```
names      20     21     22     23

peter      1      0      0      1
```

etc.

The thing is that I have 38210 observations, I have tried many of the solutions to similar answers here and either R collapses and the computer freezes or I obtain a table with 291444 variables (using as.data.frame.matrix) which doesn't makes sense since there can't be more variables than observations in the original table.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: What have you already tried? It could be an idea to try them on a subset of your data.

Comment: Just do `table(df1)!=0`

Comment: I tried using 'table' too, I keep obtaining 291414 variables, I really don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `table`

```
 +(table(df1)!=0)
```

Comment: I used table too, I obtain 291414 variables, I really don't understand.

Comment: @matiasg Try with `+(table(droplevels(df1))!=0)`